# How do I make my camera render more of the scene?

Tags: rendering, objects, camera, scene

When I go to render an image of my scene it only captures whats in the outlined area box. what I want is to capture what I see in the scene.

example picture below , I want to capture the ring and the monkey in the scene.
[image]

You can clearly see that once it renders the image its going to show the cube and parts of the ring and monkey.
I do not want to have to reposition all of my objects.

Comment: How about moving your camera.....

Comment: if i move my camera it just cuts out more of the scene i want to capture.

Comment: I mean, move the camera backwards so the objects look smaller.

Comment: if i move it left it cuts out the monkey if i move it right it cuts out the ring

Comment: oh how do i move it backwards?

Comment: Press G, Z, Z, this will move the camera along it's local Z axis. Then, move the camera backwards.

Comment: Or, you could exit the camera view, and just move it by grabbing the manipulators.

Comment: go ahead and make that your answer it work!

Comment: i selected the camera and pressed g and then z twice and it worked thank you :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the camera in the scene until the desired position is achieved.

To do this, make sure the manipulation mode is set to *local*

[image]

This will change the manipulators to use the selected object's local axis.

[image]

Then, grab the camera's local Z axis and drag it to the desired position.

[image]

Or, while you are in the camera view, you can press <kbd>G</kbd> to move the selected object (make sure the camera is selected first) Then, press <kbd>Z</kbd> once to constrain the movement to the **global** Z axis, press <kbd>Z</kbd> again to constrain the movement to the **local** Z axis. then move the mouse up or down until you get the desired camera position.

[image]